# Component is not reading object value from a const

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass value from const options to a component. Am I doing everything right?When I try to read the props in child component I just get get value="undefined". I am just trying to pass options.value to FetchRandomBet in order to use options.value in a child component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FetchRandomBet from "./fetchRandomBets";

const options = [
    { value: '1', label: 'less than 2' },
    { value: '2', label: 'more than 2' },
];

class Betslip extends Component {

    state = {
        names: [],
        odds: []
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="betslip">

                <div className="betslip-top">
                    <h1 className="text">BETSLIP</h1>
                    <p className="text-two">BET WITH US!</p>
                    <Select className="filter-menu" options={options} />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <FetchRandomBet
                        key={options.value}
                        value={options.value} />
                </div>
                console.log(options.value)
                <Button className="betnow" variant="contained">
                    Bet Now!
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Betslip;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options` is an array of object, so you can't use `options.value`. You must go to the array element and then do .value on that, i.e., `options[0].value`, `options[1].value`.

It also depends on how `FetchRandomBet` component is accepting the props. If `value` props of `FetchRandomBet` is designed to accept array then, you just pass whole `options` like below code:

```
<div>
    <FetchRandomBet key={1} value={options} />
</div>
```

Note: This is assuming your FetchRandomBet component accepts value as array.

---

Or if you want to call FetchRandomBet for each of the options value (which is highly unlikely with the context you provided in your question), you can do something like this:

```
<div>
    {
        options.map(option => <FetchRandomBet key={option.value} value={option.value} />)
    }
</div>
```

The above code will create instances of FetchRandomBet for each of the option values.

Comment: magically now I'm able to read all the data inside the object options.Thanks

Comment: What changes did you make to your code? Which of the above?

Comment: <FetchRandomBet key={1} value={options} />

Answer (score 0):

First you should not console.log inside the return statement, but its okay outside.
Next try to use this

```
const value = options.map((op) => op.value)
const label = options.map((op) => op.label)

 <FetchRandomBet
             key={value}
             value={label} />
```

You are acessing an array like if its an object so first you should enter the object and then select the key or the value.

In this way you will pass to the child component two array:
value = [1,2]
label = ["less than 2", "more than 2"]

Let me know if its what u were looking for